# Problems with arrays in Pascal

Tags: arrays, pascal

I'm new to Pascal arrays and I'd like so much learn them because my dream is to develop games. I was beginning to create a game where there's a player that moves as a wave (like Geonetry Dash game but more simply) using the keys "w" and "s". The problem is that it doesn't work. I'd like to make a trail to the player but it seems like it doesn't work! Tell me please what's wrong.

```
program gameArrays;
uses crt;     (*only crt*)
var
nx: array[1..20] of integer;                
ny: array[1..20] of integer;
x,y:integer; {*Not much used.. y not used but x only once*}
input:char;  {*Input from player*}
f,l:integer;  {*I don't know how to explain these elements.. see the code and you will understand*}
 begin
 clrscr;
 x:=10;
 nx[1]:=x;    (*nx[X] is the trail of the player.. so nx[10] is 1 so it is the last*)
 nx[2]:=x-1;
 nx[3]:=x-2;
 nx[4]:=x-3;
 nx[5]:=x-4;
 nx[6]:=x-5;
 nx[7]:=x-6;
 nx[8]:=x-7;
 nx[9]:=x-8;
 nx[10]:=x-9;
 gotoxy(nx[1],15);   (*player is  on x:10 y:15*)
 write('�');
 ny[1]:=15;
 for f:=1 to 10 do
     ny[f]:=15;           (*ny is the trail that moves up and down following the player and all are y:20 at beginning*)
 repeat
 input:=readkey;   (*if input is w then player moves up, if input is s then player moves down*)
 if input='w' then
    repeat
    for f:=1 to 10 do
        begin
             gotoxy(nx[f],ny[f]);
             write(' ');
        end;            (*delete recent activities on the screen*)
    for f:=2 to 10 do
        ny[f]:=ny[f]-1;  (*once the  "repeat until" ends, ny[2 to 10] changes.. for ex y:2 become y:1 and y:3 become y:2*)
    for f:=1 to 10 do
        begin
             gotoxy(nx[f],ny[f]);  (*write all*)
             write('�');
        end;
    ny[1]:=ny[1]-1;
    delay(100);
    until keypressed;
 if input='s' then
    repeat
    for f:=1 to 10 do
        begin
             gotoxy(nx[f],ny[f]);
             write(' ');
        end;
    for f:=2 to 10 do
        ny[f]:=ny[f]+1;
    for f:=1 to 10 do
        begin
             gotoxy(nx[f],ny[f]);
             write('�');
        end;
    ny[1]:=ny[1]+1;
    delay(100);
    until keypressed;
 until input='q';
  end.
```

Comment: *it doesn't work* is not a useful problem description, unless you're **specific** about describing in what way it **doesn't work**. Please [edit] to do so.

Comment: Try to describe what parts of the code do not work. What is your expected behavior and what does the code instead. Great developers have also to learn how to narrow down a problem and describe them properly :-) By the way: Comments should descibe why You're doing something and not what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I do not know your thought patterns as to how you came to try this solution, from experience I can tell you that objects are the best way to do these things. The program below produces what I believe you aim to achieve.

```
program gameArrays;
uses crt;
type
   piece= object
    x,y:integer;
    S:char;
   end;
var
  trail:array[0..11] of piece;{we want 11 images trailing behind}
  i,e:integer;
  input:char;
  distancemax:integer;
  distance:integer;
  run:boolean; {you should know}
begin
  distancemax:=length(trail)-1;
  distance:=distance;

for i:=0 to length(trail)-1 do {incase you change the amount of images trailing}
begin
    trail[i].y:=15;
    trail[i].x:=15;{all pieces are originally in one position then stretch out}
end;

for i:=0 to length(trail)-2 do {passing characters to the trail pieces so you can see them}
  trail[i].S:=char(2);
  {loop ends here}
  trail[length(trail)-1].S:='O'; {giving the head a different character}
  run:=true;

  while run do
  begin
    clrscr;
    for i:=0 to length(trail)-1 do {drawing}
    begin
      gotoxy(trail[i].x,trail[i].y);
      write(trail[i].S);
    end;

    if distance<distancemax then {there is a limit to how far the body should stretch}
    begin
      for i:=0 to distance do
        dec(trail[i].x); {stretches out one at a time starting from the tail}
      {loop ends here}
      inc(distance); {increases the distance at each frame}
    end;

     for i:=0 to length(trail)-2 do {makes pieces from the tail up copy the y value of the one ahead /except for the head/}
       trail[i].y:=trail[i+1].y;

    if keypressed then input:=readkey; {prevent waiting for a keypress}

    case char(input) of {button press responses}
      'w':if trail[0].y>1 then dec(trail[length(trail)-1].y);
      's':if trail[0].y<25 then inc(trail[length(trail)-1].y);
      'q':run:=false;
    end;
    delay(100);
  end;
end.
```

As for the code you provided the afterimages are not moving backwards off the screen like mine, i hadn't spent much time looking over your code that's all i really have to say. Try it out.